# Debug assertion failed in c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, assertions

I am trying to develop a code (visual studio 2012) to control a mobile robot where a sonar sensor is being read first.
I created the following function:

```
void layer1(ArRobot *robot,ArSonarDevice *sonar)// this is the avoid front collision layer
{
    double range=sonar->currentReadingPolar(-50.0,50.0)-300;
    cout<<range<<"\n";
    //read sonar in front (subtract robot diagonal) and if <200 act
    if(range<200)
    { 
        robot->setVel(-50);robot->setRotVel(50);//move backwards and rotate
        ArUtil::sleep(200);//sleep to give time to robt to react
    }
 }
```

When I run it (debug mode) I get the error:

> Debug assertion failed program C:\Windows\system32\MSVCP110D.dll

it says Expression: list iterator not dereferencable

I searched the website and came across this:
[What exactly is the "Multi-threaded Debug DLL" Runtime Library option doing in VS 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542046/what-exactly-is-the-multi-threaded-debug-dll-runtime-library-option-doing-in-v)

I made sure im using debug dll runtime library but no difference. I checked this question too and it helped me understand why this error message is displayed:
[Visual C++ find line causing "Debug Assertion failed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17279187/visual-c-find-line-causing-debug-assertion-failed)

I tried finding where exactly in the code this happens and it was found to happen at the line:

```
double range=sonar->currentReadingPolar(-50.0,50.0)-300;
```

The error happens, I thought, as soon as I run the program but I added the cout line to the function to output range and I placed it in a continuous while loop. I was surprised to know that the program was actually reading the sonar range very well with no problems. it read it several times before crashing and the values were printed correctly by cout several times before crashing. So it did not crash immediately as I thought.

So what could be the problem ?

Comment: So you figured out that the error is inside `sonar->currentReadingPolar` and decided not to show the code for it. What do you expect us to do?

Comment: @nwp please be patient with me i said i am new to this. I did not decide to hide code from you The code is part of ArRangeDevice class in the ARIA SDK. I searched for a description of this class and found it here: http://www.eecs.yorku.ca/course_archive/2008-09/W/4421/docs/classArRangeDevice.html 
and the function definition is here:
http://www.eecs.yorku.ca/course_archive/2008-09/W/4421/docs/classArRangeDevice.html#a10

and the source is here:
http://www.eecs.yorku.ca/course_archive/2008-09/W/4421/docs/ArRangeDevice_8cpp-source.html

sorry if information is missing it is not intended

Answer (score 2):

I would assume that the error message means what it says. You are trying to do something illegal with an iterator. Most likely dereferencing once it has been invalidated, or never initialized at all.

Here is Microsoft talking about these assert https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985965.aspx

Run your program under a debugger and it will break at the assert, you should be able to see exactly which line of your code is failing

The code you show doesnt have any iterators in it so we need to see more code

EDIT - seems like the failure is in the provided library. SO lets assume that the library works. The failure is therefore caused by you not using it correctly. My guess is therefore that your `sonar` value is invalid. You dont show any other code it hard to say whats wrong with it

Comment: @pm 100 thanks for replying ok I did it now I looked at the call stack it says no symbols loaded for AriaDebugVC11.dll it says iterator not incrementable in file c:\program files(x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\list but i am not using any iterator in code

Comment: @pm 100 thanks for reply the code is correct I tested it on a 32 bit machine with visual studio 2008 and it worked the exact code. Now when I move it to vs2012 it returns this error I noticed the person who setup Vs2012 was using AriadebugVC11 and runtime library was set to multi-threaded dll I changed the included file to AriaVc11 and it worked this error did not display but a different error occurred I dont understand what is the problem exactly